# can I use WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this) in another file?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-test

I have two pages, page1 and page2, in page1 I have the following code.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
    app_start = DateTime.now();
  }
  
  late DateTime app_start;
  late DateTime app_end;
  
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    final isBackground = state == AppLifecycleState.paused;
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive ||
        state == AppLifecycleState.detached) return;

    if (isBackground) {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("users")
          .doc(user!.uid)
          .get()
          .then((value) {
        loggedInUser = UserModel.fromMap(value.data());
        app_end = DateTime.now();
        final differenceInDays = app_end.difference(app_start).inSeconds;
        int? test = loggedInUser.timeActive;
        int? totalOnTime = differenceInDays + loggedInUser.timeActive!.toInt();
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(loggedInUser.uid)
            .update({"timeActive": totalOnTime});
        print(totalOnTime);
        setState(() {});
      });
    } else {
      app_start = DateTime.now();
    }
  }
```

This code simply checks how long a user has the page open by working out the time difference between when the opened and closed the page.

On my second page, I have this code in to init

```
WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this)
```

But when I enter my second page it does not remove the observer and the counter continues.

How can I set up an observer on one page then remove it when user goes to another page?

Comment: Could you show me an example?